# Как сравнить между собой две xml

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, автоматизация, pytest

Пишу тесты используя pytest и библиотеку PyHamcrest. Возникла проблема в том? что надо сравнить одну xml c другой, а именно что они схожей структуры по узлам. Посоветуйте есть ли какие то библиотеки для этого или идеи как это можно реализовать

Comment: Можете привести пример xml'ек? Т.е. какие считаются одинаковыми, а какие нет? Типо, одинаковые: `<a size="3" weight="4">abc</a>` и `<a weight="4" size="3">abc</a>`

Comment: Обход дерева и сравнения узлов на 1) список и значение аттрибутов 2) внутренний текст 3) список потомков, а потом рекурсивно для каждого потомка то же самое. Из библиотек - lxml для облегчения работы с узлами и их свойствами, но логику всё равно придётся писать самостоятельно.

Comment: вам нужен диффер? Преобразуейте обе xml в виде последовательности и сравните.

Comment: есть либа `xmltodict`. Что она делает - думаю понятно с названия. Так вот: xmltodict -> глубокая сортировка -> сравнение